# Make button in a table cell to change the color of the row it's in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to the same row that the button I click on is in. I use the jquery "closest" function but it doesn't work. I also tried .parent etc. Anyone know what I do wrong?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody class="">
    <tr class=''> //I want to change this class
        <td style=''><div class='btn btn-xs btn-success cellButton'></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
$('.cellButton').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass('info')
}
```

EDIT: I realise now that the code I posted should work (I simplified it before posting), and the problem is because it's referencing $(this) from a different function. This is the real javascript function:

```
$('.cellButton').on('click', function(){


var formData = {
  'action': 'blabla',
  'ID': ID,
};

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'includes/jquery-actions.php',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
          error: function (response) {
              alert("error!");
          },
          success: function (response) {
                  var row =  $(this).parents("tr"); //$(this) here not referencing the HTML button?)
                      row.addClass('warning');
          }
    })
```

}

Comment: maybe its not working because you don't have `)` your on click function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is working. Also
you can use [**jQuery#parents**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function. Give it the selector, it will tries to find the closest one and return that element.

**parents**

```js
$('.cellButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass('info');
});
```

```css
.info {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody class="">
    <tr class=''> 
        <td style=''><div class='btn btn-xs btn-success cellButton'>Click me</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**closest**

```js
$('.cellButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass('info');
});
```

```css
.info {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody class="">
    <tr class=''> 
        <td style=''><div class='btn btn-xs btn-success cellButton'>Click me</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**UPDATED**

There is an issue with context.

You can keep your `this` in above the ajax request and use that variable inside the `function`

```
var that = this;

...

success: function (response) {
      var row =  $(that).parents("tr"); 
      row.addClass('warning');
}
```

Or just use arrow functions

```
success: (response) => {
      var row =  $(this).parents("tr"); 
      row.addClass('warning');
}
```

Comment: @JamesB Updated

Comment: Thanks a lot, just making the new variable fixed it :D
But I didn't understand the arrow function code, that gave a syntax error...

Comment: @JamesB arrow functions: - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjV7Jest8LWAhWIuRQKHc4fDqUQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AFQjCNEJ7j1iiQ3p-iy7u9L78rzUyEGUHg